# codeigniter always opens welcome-page

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

edit:

**Solved - mod_rewrite was the problem**

---

I can't get CI to work as described in the tutorial.
No matter how I fiddle with the path or the settings - it is not working

My Setup:

- ubuntu on local machine
- no `.htaccess`
- default routing
- config:

  - `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/~myuser/ci/';`
  - `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`
  - `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';`
- one controller named users.php class Users with a "listone" method

I try calling

- http://localhost/~myuser/ci/index.php?users/listone -> welcome page
- http://localhost/~myuser/ci/index.php/users/listone -> 404

I had different routing configured, to use users/listone as default. That was working, but then I was unable to access other methods.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to follow the tutorial, but it seems as if its not working as described.

edit:
even with a slash at the end of base_url its not working, neither when empty

i get a **server** 404 when I call index.php/users/listone , not the one CI has.

The controller: added a index-method. - which is not reachable

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller {
    public function listone($page = 'listall')
    {
        echo $page;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'listone';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait I missed something: `users/listone` worked when set as `default_controller` in `routes.php`? Can we see that controller? The missing `base_url` trailing slash definitely needs to be fixed but shouldn't affect routing.

Comment: Aha, a *server* 404. That's significant but also strange.  See if `print_r($_SERVER)` reveals anything useful.

Comment: please post your routing configuration

Comment: as said in the question: I have the default-routing.´

$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';´

Comment: For `http://localhost/~myuser/ci/index.php/users/listone` to work you will still need `mod_rewrite` enabled in Apache, and you may also need to set `RewriteBase /home/myuser/ci/` (preferably with a .htaccess in your CI directory).

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost/~myuser/ci/index.php?/users/listone ? Both question mark and slash are needed on some server set-ups, you can change your index_page var to reflect it.

Comment: thanks to you all - the note about mod_rewrite was the solution. my little test-setup ran without it. stupid me - should have thought about checking my configuration.

Comment: you can always answer your own question too, so it doesn't stay open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

My test-system was missing mod_rewrite.

An indicator for that problem might be, that calling `http://host/directory/index.php/conntroller` shows a 404. - not a CodeIgniter-404, but a apache 404.

Thanks all for helping me.